# Verificar se uma Tag tem uma classe usando Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, table, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou criando para fazer uma busca em uma tabela Bootstrap de acordo com oque o usuário seleciona em um select. Para isso eu estou colocando uma classe com o valor igual o do valor da `<option>` do `select`.

Estou usando apenas o TypeScript. **SEM JQUERY**.

E estou tentando fazer com um `switch`, mas está dando erro. Minha função está da seguinte forma:

```
function mudarPesquisaSelect() {
    var tr = document.getElementById('tbody').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var valorSelect = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("grupo"));

    switch (valorSelect.value) {

        case "P":
            for (var ab = 0; ab < (tr.length - 1); ab++) {
                if (tr.classList.contains('P')) {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            break;

        case "A":
            for (var ab = 0; ab < (tr.length - 1); ab++) {
                if (tr.classList.contains('A')) {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "S":
            for (var ab = 0; ab < (tr.length - 1); ab++) {
                if (tr.classList.contains('S')) {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "F":
            for (var ab = 0; ab < (tr.length - 1); ab++) {
                if (tr.classList.contains('F')) {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "T":
            for (var ab = 0; ab < (tr.length - 1); ab++) {
                if (tr.classList.contains('T')) {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "O":
            for (var ab = 0; ab < (tr.length - 1); ab++) {
                if (tr.classList.contains('O')) {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "All":
            for (var ab = 0; ab < (tr.length - 1); ab++) {
                if (tr.classList.contains('All')) {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[ab].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        break;

        default:
    }
}
```

Mas está dando um erro neste trecho:

```
if (tr.classList.contains(className)) {
```

No erro está escrito o seguinte:

> Property 'classlist' does not exist on type
>   'HTMLCollectionOf < HTMLTableRowElement>'

E oque eu estou tentando fazer é verificar se a `<tr>` contém a classe "P", no caso. Alguém aí com mais conhecimento poderia me dar uma ajuda com opções que eu tenho para contornar este erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No original esta:

```
if (tr.classList.contains(className)) {
```

Altere para:

```
if (tr[ab].classList.contains(className)) {
```

Quando você chamou o método `getElementsByTagName` ele buscou todos os elementos com a tag `'tr'` retornando uma coleção de elementos. Mas na sua comparação você esqueceu de indicar o índice do elemento que você esta acessando.

Comment: Não acredito que era só isso, um pequeno detalhe que esqueci de colocar... Obrigado